# output variables in view that have been manipulated in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

class `MyClass`

```
class MyClass < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :attr0, :attr1 

end
```

controller `MyController`

```
class MyController < ApplicationController

  helper_method :set_var

  def index
    @myclasses = MyClass.all
  end

  def set_var(foo)
    @var0 = foo.attr0
    @var1 = foo.attr1
  end

end
```

view

```
 <table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Head0</th>
      <th>Head1</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% @myclasses.each do |myclass| %>
      <% set_var(myclass) %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= @var0 %></td>
        <td><%= @var1 %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to output `var0` and `var1` after they have been manipulated in `set_var`, but i must call `set_var(myclass)` first to cycle through the instances of MyClass. What I did above puts nothing in my view. Is there an elegant way to to this without handling html code in my method set_var?

---

edit:

as stated below this is not an option, as my example is extremely simplified

```
 <% @myclasses.each do |myclass| %>
   <tr>
     <td><%= myclass.attr0 %></td>
     <td><%= myclass.attr1 %></td>
   </tr>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@myclasses` as written above isn't a controller instance variable, but rather an instance variable of the class itself. To use the `@myclasses` notation in the view it needs to be an instance variable:

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  def some_method
    @myclasses = MyClass.all
  end
end
```

That aside, I'm not a fan of what you're doing anyway; it seems like you should either be accessing the properties directly, using a model method, using a decorator, or even a regular helper.

---

*Edit after question edited to be correct.*

Instance variables are exposed pre-render; new ones created on-the-fly wouldn't be available at that time. You could *try* initializing them in your action and *modifying* them, but major yuck.

You're conflating concerns here in a really horrible way: whatever this method is needs to be in a decorator or the model etc., calling *back* in to the controller in a loop to modify instance variables for each iteration has *got* to be considered an anti-pattern on all counts.

Comment: is putting an instance variable in a controller bad style or does it have any negative effects on other levels? i can use @myclasses fine, though its declared in the controller

Comment: @Zois Huh, I would not have expected that to work; that's very confusing/misleading at the very least. Rails would have to decide precedence (i.e., what if you had an instance attribute with the same name as a class attribute?) when mixing the two variable types, so I think it should be avoided.

Comment: @Zois What version of Rails are you using? When I set a class instance variable it does not show up in the view (as I would expect it not to). Are you *positive* this is actually working? I just don't see how it can be.

Comment: i'm using v3.2.6 and i'm declaring the instance variables within the controllers index method

Comment: @Zois Then your question should reflect that, class instance are a very different thing-it appears you're a bit confused on the terminology.

Comment: oh you are right, i forgot the index method in my example! sorry for that- nevertheless they are called instance variables if i'm not mistaken?

Comment: @Zois They're instance variables if they're defined in instance methods. In your original code, however, it was not: it was an instance variable *of the class itself*, not of *instances* of the class, as I said in my answer.

Comment: @Zois In any case, I suspect the way rendering works mean it wouldn't work like this anyway, and that instance variables are exposed *pre*-render, so *new* ones wouldn't be reflected. You could *try* to see if using already-initialized ones works, but doing it like this seems *totally* non-sensical to me: you could just as easily call the method in the main controller action, or move it out of the controller altogether.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30791/discussion-between-zois-and-dave-newton)

Answer (score 0):

```
<% @myclasses.each do |myclass| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= myclass.attr0 %></td>
    <td><%= myclass.attr1 %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Any reason you cant do that?

edit: If you want to manipulate them, define it in the model.

```
def modify_attr0
    attr0.to_s+" foo"
end
```

In the view

```
myclass.modify_attr0
```

Comment: yes, my example above is extremely simplified and this is not an option, im going to edit my question.. thanks

Comment: actually what i want to do is use the data from the attributes of `myclass` to manipulate other data and output the results of that